# javafx dropshadow grows event area - cause problems with 3d button style

Tags: css, events, button, javafx, dropshadow

I have created some 3d buttons using css and dropShadow effect. It's beautiful but i encountered some problems with event capturing. When i add a dropShadow effect to a button, the area where the event is captured by the button grows.

Two sides effects from that :

- the button is pressed when i click next to it
- the MOUSE_CLICKED event is not fired because the dropshadow area
  reduces when i press the button (3d effect with css)

I have found a way to get round this problem by adding the button in a group and apply the dropshadow effect to the group. It works but it is not beautiful.

Do you know another way? Don't you think it is weird to take into account the dropshadow area in event bubbling?

[image]

```
/**
 * The Class ButtonExample.
 */
public class ButtonShadowSample extends Application {

  /** {@inheritDoc} */
  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    stage.setTitle("Button Shadow");

    Button button = new Button("BOUTON1");
    button.getStyleClass().add("realistic-button");
    button.setOnAction(evt -> System.out.println("Button1 action"));

    Button button2 = new Button("BOUTON2");
    button2.getStyleClass().add("realistic-button2");
    button2.setOnAction(evt -> System.out.println("Button2 action"));
    Group group = new Group(button2);
    group.getStyleClass().add("group");

    VBox vbox = new VBox(button, group);
    vbox.setSpacing(5);

    stage.setScene(new Scene(vbox));

    stage.getScene().getStylesheets().add(ButtonShadowSample.class.getResource("ButtonShadowSample.css").toExternalForm());
    stage.show();
  }

  /**
   * The main method.
   *
   * @param args the arguments
   */
  public static void main(String... args) {
    launch(args);
  }
}
```

The css :

```
.root {
    -fx-background: white;
}

.realistic-button {
    -fx-background-color:
        #000000,
        linear-gradient(#464646 0%, #323232 100%);
    -fx-background-insets: 0 0 0 0, 0 1 5 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 5, 5;
    -fx-padding: 5;
    -fx-pref-height: 34;
    -fx-min-height: 34;
    -fx-alignment: bottom-center;
    -fx-font-family: "Helvetica";
    -fx-font-size: 12px;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 10, 0.4, 3, 3);
}

.realistic-button:pressed {
    -fx-background-color:
        #000000,
        linear-gradient(#464646 0%, #323232 100%);
    -fx-background-insets: 2 1 0 1, 2 0 2 1;
    -fx-background-radius: 5, 5;
    -fx-padding: 5 4 2 6;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 5, 0.5, 0, 1);
}

.realistic-button2 {
    -fx-background-color:
        #000000,
        linear-gradient(#464646 0%, #323232 100%);
    -fx-background-insets: 0 0 0 0, 0 1 5 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 5, 5;
    -fx-pref-height: 34;
    -fx-min-height: 34;
    -fx-padding: 5;
    -fx-alignment: bottom-center;
    -fx-font-family: "Helvetica";
    -fx-font-size: 12px;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}

.realistic-button2:pressed {
    -fx-background-color:
        #000000,
        linear-gradient(#464646 0%, #323232 100%);
    -fx-background-insets: 2 1 0 1, 2 0 2 1;
    -fx-background-radius: 5, 5;
    -fx-padding: 5 4 2 6;
}

.group {
    -fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 10, 0.4, 3, 3);
}

.group:pressed {
    -fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 5, 0.5, 0, 1);
}
```

Comment: It's just the way it is, I doubt you will find a better solution than the one you offer in your question: "to get round this problem by adding the button in a group and apply the dropshadow effect to the group", perhaps you should post that as a [self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: I've not found the way to post that as a self-answer even if i have reached 15 reputation points i can't see the checkbox that say "Answer your own question".

Answer (score 0):

I had a [similar issue](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2577503) with the drop shadow effect, when it was only applied on hover. The effect was that the layout initially was recalculated. I think something similar is happening here.

The solution is to add some padding to the button:

```
button.setPadding(new Insets(10));
```

or as CSS style:

```
-fx-padding: 10px;
```

Comment: Padding is only for the text inside the button. No effect on button event area.